# store alcohol tinctured herbs in polypropylene for extended time

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Can I store alcohol tinctured medicinal herbs in the 2 oz. food grade polypropylene cups  (PP 5) for about a week?  I would like to have several "doses" ready to go because they are taken several times a day, and I would like to have several days ready to use at all times.  Thanks

Comment: Keeping alcohol in plastic is usually better avoided. Hard to tell on individual basis.

Answer (score 0):

The alcohols should not be an issue, it is used for storing often.  Some oils will affect it.

Here is a random [guide](https://www.prinsco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/HP-Chemical-Resistance-Tech-Note.pdf) that includes a few common oils.